# confusion on anchor argument of position component

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm new to flame and flutter and have some questions about PositionComponent's anchor argument.

According to flame help doc: "So if you, for example, wanted to position a child 50 logical pixels above the ***center*** of the parent you would do this:"

```
Future<void> onLoad() async {
  final parent = PositionComponent(
    position: Vector2(100, 100),
    size: Vector2(100, 100),
    anchor: Anchor.center,
  );
  final child = PositionComponent(position: Vector2(0, -50));
  await parent.add(child);
}
```

However, in my experiment, the child component appears at 50 pixels above the ***top-left*** corner of its parent.

Below is the snippet of the code I used, with PositionComponent replaced with RectangleComponent in order to visualize the effect of the anchor.

```
final parent = RectangleComponent(
  position: Vector2(100, 100),
  size: Vector2(100, 100),
  anchor: Anchor.center,
)..setColor(Colors.blue);
add(parent);

final child = RectangleComponent(
  position: Vector2(0, -50),
  size: Vector2(10, 10),
)..setColor(Colors.yellow);
parent.add(child);
```

[image]

Using Flame 1.6.0 with Flutter 3.7.3 on Windows 11.

Appreciate it if anyone can help point out what I might have done incorrectly. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely correct, those docs are wrong. I'll update them now.

The anchor only determines two things:

1. Where the position of the component itself should be calculated from.
2. What part of the component that the component should rotate around.

So if you'd want to place a component 50 pixels above its parent you would do it like this:

```dart
final parent = RectangleComponent(
  position: Vector2(100, 100),
  size: Vector2(100, 100),
)..setColor(Colors.blue);
add(parent);

final child = RectangleComponent(
  position: Vector2(0, -50),
  size: Vector2(10, 10),
  anchor: Anchor.bottomLeft,
)..setColor(Colors.yellow);
parent.add(child);
```